# Replace dot in a specific column

Tags: r

I have the DF:

```
KEY <- c(12,55,889)
FOOD <- c("RICE","TOMATO","MANGO")
CAR <- c("BMW.3","FERRARI.12","TOYOTA.58")
DF <- data.frame(KEY,FOOD,CAR)
```

How do I replace the dot in the "CAR" column?

I expect this result

```
    KEY <- c(12,55,889)
    FOOD <- c("RICE","TOMATO","MANGO")
    CAR <- c("BMW3","FERRARI12","TOYOTA58")
    DF <- data.frame(KEY,FOOD,CAR)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub("\\.","",CAR)
[1] "BMW3"      "FERRARI12" "TOYOTA58"
```

Comment: How would my code be using pipe? DF<- DF %>% ....

Comment: @BrunoAvila No need for pipe `CAR=gsub("\\.","",CAR)` and then data frame it.